# How to display remote queue managers from client host using CLI

Tags: ibm-mq

I am new to IBM MQ, wanted to know if its possible to display remote queue managers from client host using CLI, like I can successfully see the remote queue managers in webconsole of client-ibm-mq but how to check that from CLI or PCF or REST call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible to use remote MQ commands (such as PCF or MQSC) to display the queue managers on a machine.

However, using the MQ Console or the REST API it is possible. Do an HTTP GET from the following URL (changing the domain accordingly):-

```
http://localhost:9080/ibmmq/rest/v1/admin/qmgr
```

This will show you output like the following:-

```
{"qmgr": [
  {
    "name": "MQG1",
    "state": "running"
  },
  {
    "name": "MQG2",
    "state": "ended"
  }
]}
```

For more information on this particular REST API, see [reference page for HTTP GET from /admin/qmgr](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=adminqmgr-get)

Comment: Thanks @Morag Hughson.
I tried this with https://restninja.io/ rest client
http://10.135.34.204:1414/ibmmq/rest/v1/admin/qmgr it did not worked here 1414 is listener port.
As it did not worked I tried with 9443 port which I use to access webconsole : https://10.135.34.204:9443/ibmmq/console/#/manage/qmgr
rest call as below: still not working
http://10.135.34.204:9443/ibmmq/rest/v1/admin/qmgr

Comment: Any idea what is wrong in my rest call

Comment: You should probably tell us what "not working" means,  are you receiving a error?  Have you looked in the web console logs?

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc.
I tried with another tool, i.e. postman for REST call.
I checked webconsole log:
```[AUDIT   ] MQWB0104E: The REST API request to 'https://172.20.190.95:9443/ibmmq/rest/v1/admin/qmgr/' is not authenticated.```

Comment: I think I need to add authentication user id and password.
But somehow as I know, while adding remote queue manager, by CLI: setmqweb by providing connection details json as per link: ```https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=arqm-connecting-remote-queue-manager-mq-console-by-using-command-line``

```setmqweb remote add -uniqueName "QM1REMOTE1" -qmgrName "QM1" -ccdtURL "/var/mqm/errors/clientConn.json"```
If try with user id and password which is my linux login uid and pwd it does not work.

Any idea, what could be proper user id and password

Comment: I can execute it successfully, using curl commands and passing -k and -u uid:pwd
 curl -k https://<IP of machine>:9443/ibmmq/rest/v1/admin/qmgr/ -X GET -u mqadmin:mqadmin
it worked.